# Russian Horror/Fantasy Film with magical constructs as farm labourers

Tags: story-identification, movie, folklore

A film, I'm 95% sure was Russian. I watched it within the last two years and I got the impression it was not very old, say post-2015.
Filmed in colour.
The scene I remember was a raggedy creature that was returning to a peasant farm across the farmyard. It was a collection of sticks, bones, and tools and looked like a spoked wheel without a rim, but with an animal skull for a head. About 1m diameter, and moved by rolling along on the spokes.
It was ill, or broken, and entered the farmhouse, where the family were very blasé about the whole thing - because they created, and animated, these creatures using some kind of folk-magic.
The shot of it crossing the yard was very creepy.
Anybody recognise the film (or possibly TV series)?
I thought maybe it was "Gogol", but a google search doesn't throw up a mention of the creature, and I don't want to watch the whole series again.

Comment: Intriguing. I wonder if it has something to do with communism?

Comment: What period of time was filmed in the movie? Our days or some past time?

Comment: Past - feudal type level.

Comment: Something like Viy 3d https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPcPtizGymc ?

Comment: Yes. Similar setting to Viy/Gogol. But I don't think it's that particular film/series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the 2017 Estonian movie titled NOVEMBER. The farm equipment "creatures" are magically assembled and called kratts. [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19QZy1YHL50)

Comment: Nice find! Now I need to find myself a copy...

Comment: They look weird https://europasf.eu/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/November_Andrus.jpg

Comment: Great! That's it! Thanks.